# linked representation of sparse matrices

Tags: file, data-structures, sparse-matrix

for sparse matrices i had put a question about its linked representation.
there were two lists to be implemented for a nine zero elements of a 5x8 matrix.....one is the coloumn list and another one is the row list.....
now here is a problem both the lists have properties as follows:
1) row list:- row,col,data,right
2) coloumn list:-row,col,data,down

the link is through either the down or right field

i have created a sparse matrice as follows:

_1_*2*_3_*4*_5_*6*_7_*8*_
1|   1  0  0  0  0  6  0  9
2|   0  2  0  0  0  0  7  0
3|   0  0  3  0  0  0  0  8
4|   0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0
5|   0  0  0  0  5  0  0  0

i googled around and finally got some representation in ibm site

but the real headache for me is i am just not getting enough help how to represent the elements as in both the list.
should both the list contain all 9 non zero elements?
can anybody suggest something?

Comment: Did you just copy and paste your homework here?

Comment: i have tried my way out,i am doing an open university course and there is no help for it,so thot of asking expert help,m sorry to say but that was very insulting!

Comment: @shridatt: I'm sorry to say, but I find it insulting that you paste your homework here, not even adding a single word of yours, and expect others to solve it for you. See [How to ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). I (and others) will be glad to *help*, but won't just *do* it for you.  Tell us what you don't understand, what you did, what you think you understood, what you can't get to work, etc.

Comment: i dont have the papers with me i have worked on..ill update the question with the answer that i tried for this

Comment: What approach have you tried so far?

Comment: sir,i have been trying from text books..but i need a solid solution in my mind of my questions then only ill open this question again....dont want it to be termed as homework again...thanx :)

Answer (score 1):

the link list representation of the matrix is

```
|5|9|9| |-> |1|1|1| | -> |1|6|6| | -> |1|8|9| | -> |2|2|2| |->|2|7|7| |-> |3|3|3| |->|3|8|8| |->|4|4|4| |->|5|5|5|null|
```

here first node show the total number of row and columns.the 2nd ,3rd and so on shows the the values of row, column ,nonzero values of the corresponding values.

```
1| 1 0 0 0 0 6 0 9 
2| 0 2 0 0 0 0 7 0
3| 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 8 
4| 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 
5| 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0
```